# How do I change the value extracting data from a json file for a nested div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

This is my code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="dash-box dash-box-color-1">
                <div class="dash-box-icon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="dash-box-body">
                    <span class="dash-box-count">someNumber</span>
                    <span class="dash-box-title">sometitle</span>
                </div>

                <div class="dash-box-action">
                    <button>More Info</button>
                </div>              
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dash-box dash-box-color-2">
                <div class="dash-box-icon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="dash-box-body">
                    <span class="dash-box-count">someNumber</span>
                    <span class="dash-box-title">someTitle</span>
                </div>

                <div class="dash-box-action">
                    <button>More Info</button>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract data values from a json file and display it at the someNumber at someNumbers place. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: How is the JSON file being provided? Is there an input tag for a user to upload a file or is it being retrieved over a network request? Or does it live alongside the code already created?

Comment: It is present in the file system and is being retrieved over a network request.